# Distributed (multi-device) implementation of sequence-to-sequence models in TensorFlow?

Tags: gpgpu, tensorflow, multi-gpu, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html) is a very good tutorial on training a **sequence-to-sequence model** in TensorFlow. I just interested to know if there is a **distributed version** which leverage **a set of GPUs on a single machine** for better performance?

[TensorFlow white paper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) has been mentioned that it is possible to train a large multilayer recurrent neural network (See **Figure 8** and "**model parallel training**" section) as used in [Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural). Anybody know if the current tutorial cover model parallel training? 
If no, how to improve the original tutorial to leverage a set of GPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example covers multi-gpu training https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#training-a-model-using-multiple-gpu-cards

Basically to utilize multiple GPU's, you have to use tensorflow's built in scoping to explicitly tell it which device to run on. You can have a bunch of GPUs run in parallel, and then use some device to sum up the results. This involves a lot of tensorflow scoping, which must be explicitly done. So to use gpu 0, you could have a call similar to this:

```
        with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
            #do your calculations
```

and then somewhere else in your code you have a synchronization step:

```
        with tf.device(aggregation_device):
            #make your updates
```

The link explains this pretty well, but hopefully this can get you started

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: 
https://github.com/shixing/xing_rnn/tree/master/Seq2Seq

it implements a attention-based seq2seq model which can put each layer on different GPU.